# Find all m-tuples that sum to n

Tags: r

I want to find ALL the non-negative integer solutions to the equation i+j+k+l+m=n where n is a non-negative integer. That is, I want to find all possible 5-tuples (i,j,k,l,m) with respect to a certain n, in R.

I wrote a code which is not working. I am suspicious there is something wrong in the looping.

For your convenience, I have taken n=3, so I am basically trying to compute all vectors (i,j,k,l,m) which are 35 in number, and the matrix a(35 by 5) is the matrix that is supposed to display those vectors. The whole thing is in the function "sample(n)", where if I put n=3 i.e. sample(3) when called will give me the matrix a. Please note that a (35 by 5) is defined beforehand with all entries 0.

```
sample=function(n){
i=0
j=0
k=0
l=0
m=0
for(p in 1:35){
while(i<=3){
while(j<=3){
while(k<=3){
while(l<=3){
m=n-(i+j+k+l)
if(m>-1){
a[p,]=c(i,j,k,l,m)
}
l=l+1}
k=k+1}
j=j+1}
i=i+1}
}
return(a)
}
```

When I call `sample(3)`, I get my original a i.e. the matrix with all elements 0. What is wrong with this code? Please rectify it.

Comment: Don't call a function `sample`. That's an important base function, which you shouldn't mask.

Comment: I don't see where you initialize `a` in your function.

Comment: @Roland, I already initialized a, don't worry.

Comment: Why should *I* worry? You didn't initialize it inside your function, which is where you should do that.

Comment: No I intialized it before the function statements. I did not intialize it inside the function. Are they not equivalent?

Comment: You should study the topic of variable scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your code isn't answering your stated problem (as I understand it), on top of possible errors in your code.

One way to think of the problem is that, given the quadruple (i,j,k,l), the value of m = n - (i + j + k + l), while noting that the quadruple (i,j,k,l) is constrained so that  n >= i+j+k+l  AND i,j,k,l >= 0. For example, consider the following algorithm:

- Let i freely take any value between 0 and n.
- Given i, j can take values between 0 and n-i.
- Given (i,j), k takes values between 0 and n-i-j.
- Given (i,j,k), l takes values between 0 and n-i-j-k.
- Given (i,j,k,l), m is defined as m = n - i - j - k -l.

The following code ought to answer your question. Please comment if this is not what you were looking for.

```
sample.example = function(n){
  a=array(0,c(0,5))
  for(i in 0:n){
    for(j in seq(from=0,to=n-i,by=1)){
      for(k in seq(from=0,to=n-i-j,by=1)){
        for(l in seq(from=0,to=n-i-j-k,by=1)){
          m = n - i -j - k - l
          a = rbind(a,c(i,j,k,l,m))
     }}}}
  return(a)
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working!! Now this was not part of my original question but suppose I want to store the output in a matrix which I want to access later, maybe use the matrix in ANOTHER matrix. How can I possibly store the output in a matrix? Because right after I get away from the function, a is lost!!

Comment: @yedaynara That's how functions in R work. You just need to assign the result.

Comment: You can assign a function's output by giving it a name. If you have a function such as `sample.example` in the above answer, you can enter `saved.output = sample.example(n)` into your console after placing that function into your environment. Then `saved.output` will be a matrix with the output from that function that you can access later on.

Comment: Oooh lol, this was a really dumb question. I have used this for so many times!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think a brute-force approach will bring you much joy for this task. Instead you should look for existing functions that can be used and are efficient (i.e. implemented in C/C++).

```
n <- 3
library(partitions)
blockparts(rep(n, 5), n)
#[1,] 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#[2,] 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
#[4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 1 0
#[5,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

Comment: Can I store this data in a matrix having 5 columns and so many rows? If so, how?

Comment: `a <- blockparts(rep(n, 5), n); t(a)`

Comment: Thanks but when I run this code on R, it says partitions is not a library.

Comment: Did you install the package? It seems to me like you should read [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).